# Laravel Middleware redirect with route

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware, laravel-5.8

```
$memberrole = new MemberRole();
$abc        = new MemberRoleRepository($memberrole);
$user       = \Auth::user();
$role       = $abc->where('member_id', $user['id'])->first();
$role_id    = $role['role_id'];

if($role_id == 'admin' || $role_id == 'teacher') {
    return $next($request);
}

return redirect()->route('something belong to normal user');
```

I separate route admin to admin.php in route
I want if user trying to typing admin route with role is normal user website redirect normal user to normal page. But I always get prefix admin/[route I want to redirect].
Please show me how can I fix this issue, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it with:

```
return redirect('absolute route');
```

Remove route save my time, but I think I got something wrong. I will update if I find out. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

you can use it

```
return redirect('admin/url');
```